# Pascal with multiple condition

Tags: while-loop, conditional-statements, pascal

I'm having a problem with putting multiple conditions in a while loop.

```
WRITE('Entrez le nombre n°1 : ');
READLN(e);

mv := e;
WHILE (not ((e mod 5 = 0) or (e mod 2 = 0))) or (not(e = 0)) DO 
BEGIN
    IF (e > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        i := i+1;
        WRITE('Entrez le nombre n°', i,' : ');
        READLN(e);
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WRITE('Entrez le nombre n°', i,' : ');
        READLN(e);
    END;

    IF (mv < e ) THEN
    BEGIN
        im := i;
        mv := e;
    END;
END;
```

What I want to do is that if e (INTEGER) is divisible by 2 and divisible by 5, or e=0 to exit the while loop. But these conditions don't seem to work in Pascal...

Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: This still doesn't work... I'm going to post the whole Program

Comment: Not the whole program. Just enough of  it to actually demonstrate the problem you're having, and [edit] your question to add the code there.

Comment: This is What You told me to put but when I have e = 0 it doesn't stop the While loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"WHILE" will continue to perform the action as long as the condition is true.

So if e=0 it will enter the loop. when it is "1" for example you will be able to exit.

if you wish to exit the loop on 0 you must change to UNTIL loop, or check if e=0 inside the loop and BREAK, or change the condition to NOT.

Comment: I have edited the WHILE DO loops condition but when e = 10, my loop still runs, I'm going to try with the UNTIL loop

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just resolved my problem, I actually put an UNTIL loop as @Eden said so. And it actually worked. I tryed using that before but didn't change the :

```
<>
```

to

```
=
```

Here is my new Program and works perfectly

```
PROGRAM ALGO;
```

VAR
    mv, e, i, im : LONGINT;

BEGIN
    mv := 0;
    i := 1;
    im := 1;
    e := 0;

```
WRITE('Entrez le nombre n°1 : ');
READLN(e);

mv := e;

REPEAT 
    IF (e > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        i := i+1;
        WRITE('Entrez le nombre n°', i,' : ');
        READLN(e);
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WRITE('Entrez le nombre n°', i,' : ');
        READLN(e);
    END;

    IF (mv < e ) THEN
    BEGIN
        im := i;
        mv := e;
    END;
UNTIL ((e mod 5 = 0) and (e mod 2 = 0)) or (e = 0);

WRITELN('Le plus grand de ces nombres est ',mv,'.');
WRITELN('C''est le nombre n°',im,'.');

END.
```

Thank you for your help Eden and Ken White.
David

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little off (in your code). You're missing a `not`:

Here's a sample that should help:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Math;

var
  e: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  e := 3;
  while not (((e mod 5 = 0) and (e mod 2 = 0)) or (e = 0)) do
  begin
    WriteLn('e: ', e);
    e := RandomRange(0, 25);
  end;
  WriteLn('Done.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.. If e = 10 the loop still runs but it is divisible by 5 and 2 at the same time. And If e = 0 the loop should stop but it still runs

Comment: See my edit (there's a grouping error in my original post).

Comment: @Rigaux: It's great you solved your problem, but the answer you posted (and the answer you accepted) do not answer the question you asked, which was how to use multiple conditions in a `while` loop. *Use a different type loop* does not answer that question, because it doesn't explain *how to use multiple conditions in a `while` loop*.